# Data is not passed from AngularJS controller to NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, post, express

I am attempting to pass some values from my client-side AngularJS script to a server-side NodeJS script. I set up the POST request like so:

```
    $scope.addUser = function() {
        console.log($.param($scope.user));
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/addUser',
            data: $.param($scope.user),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).
        success( function(response) {
            console.log("success");
        }).
        error( function(response) {
            console.log("error");
        });

    };
```

The $scope.user variable is `{ name: "john", email: "doe" }`, and evaluates to `name=john&email=doe` when passed through `$.param($scope.user)`. I originally thought the problem was the content-type of the request, which was originally a JSON object. After reading about similar problems I changed the content-type to x-www-form-urlencoded, but still could not grab the data from the POST request.

Here is the server-side NodeJS script that is hit with the POST request:

```
app.post('/addUser', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

I know the server-side script is being reached, as I can print out data such as req.method, but attempting to print req.params results in just { }.

Why are my POST parameters not going through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request bodies are not saved to `req.params`. You need to add a middleware to parse the request body for you. `req.params` is for `key=value` pairs supplied as part of the URL (e.g. POSTing to "/foo/bar?baz=bla" would result in `req.params.baz === 'bla'`).

Some example solutions:

- [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) - parses only **application/json** and **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** request bodies.
- [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) - parses **application/json**, **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, and **multipart/form-data**. This is what was used in the body parser in Express 3. I'm not sure if there is an "official" Express middleware for it for Express 4.
- [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) - parses **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** and **multipart/form-data**. It does not save files to disk itself, but instead presents files as readable streams. The API differs from formidable(/body parser from Express 3). There are a few Express middleware available for busboy:

  - [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) - a thin wrapper that merely sets up a Busboy instance on your `req`. You can set it to automatically start parsing the request, or you can pipe the request manually to `req.busboy` when you want to start.
  - [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) - provides an interface more similar to the Express 3 body parser middleware (with `req.body` and `req.files` set).
  - [reformed](https://github.com/mscdex/reformed) - a new module that provides a layer on top of Busboy to provide mechanisms similar to formidable (e.g. saving uploaded files to disk) but also other features such as field validation.

Comment: This led me to the right answer. I had to use connect.parseBody, as the express package doesn't come previously installed and I had trouble installing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using express.js your POST fields are received as part of the body not the URL so you need use `body` instead of `params`:

```
app.post('/addUser', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);//also possible req.body.name | req.body.email
});
```

How about trying a simpler POST something like this (for testing purposes *only*):

```
  $http.post('/addUser',{ "name": "john", "email": "doe" }).success(function(response) {
           console.log("success");
          }).error(function(err){
             console.log("failure")
          });
```

Please note that Params are used as URL parameters; something like this:

```
app.get('/addUser/:userID', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.params.userID);
});
```